# Beautiful bar plot with mean and coefficient of variation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting some values that has the mean and the coefficient of variation of that means. The thing is that I do't know how to put both values on the plot and see it kinda beautiful. My approach is like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
colors = ["b", "g", "r", "c", "m", "y", "k", "w"]
models = ["DQN", "DDQN", "DoubleDQN", "DoubleDDQN", "RND", "DQNfD"]
means = [1.90, 0.67, 1.32, 2.02, 0.90, 1.92]
cvs =   [1.34, 2.32, 1.44, 1.32, 2.03, 1.33]
cont = 0
for m, c, mean, cv in zip(models, colors, means, cvs):
    plt.bar(cont, mean, label = "CV = {:.2f}".format(cv), color = c)
    plt.text(cont-0.16, mean + 0.03, "{:.2f}".format(mean))
    plt.title("Mean Episode Reward at Test")
    plt.ylabel('Mean Episode Reward')
    plt.xticks(np.arange(len(models)), models)
    cont+=1
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
```

And the output is this:
[image: 1]
I want to see the values of the means and the cvs both graphically and numerically, but I can't figure out how to do it (If the cv is not possible, nevermind). Error bars for the cv, isn't the best option as we are not at the same scale, but having them at the legend is so ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to admit I'm not sure what the desired outcome really is; so here is simply a proposal for beautification:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

colors = ["b", "g", "r", "c", "m", "y", "k", "w"]
models = ["DQN", "DDQN", "DoubleDQN", "DoubleDDQN", "RND", "DQNfD"]
means = [1.90, 0.67, 1.32, 2.02, 0.90, 1.92]
cvs =   [1.34, 2.32, 1.44, 1.32, 2.03, 1.33]


plt.bar(models, means, color=colors[:len(means)])

for i, (mean, cv) in enumerate(zip(means, cvs)):
    annotkw = dict(textcoords="offset points", ha="center")
    plt.annotate("CV = {:.2f}".format(cv), xy=(i, mean), xytext=(0, -3),
                 va = "top", fontsize=8, fontweight="bold",
                 color="w", **annotkw)
    plt.annotate("{:.2f}".format(mean), xy=(i, mean), xytext=(0, 1),
                 va = "bottom", **annotkw)

plt.title("Mean Episode Reward at Test")
plt.ylabel('Mean Episode Reward')

plt.margins(y=0.1)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know if it is the best approach, but it is definitely better than mine. The visualization of CV I think that could be better. Thanks a lot.